# Using Solr or ElasticSearch as API best practices

Tags: javascript, api, solr, elasticsearch

I'm looking at using Solr or ElasticSearch for a few clientside javascript apps.  In one instance I could call the API directly.

I'm pretty new to this concept and one of the first things that came to mind is how do you avoid security related issues like people issuing delete commands against the API?  Is it appropriate to hide the search API behind a layer, like a small PHP or Sinatra API to that client interacts with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Is it appropriate to hide the search API behind a layer, like a small PHP or Sinatra API to that client interacts with?

If you care for security, the answer is Undoubtedly - **YES**.
NodeJS is great for those kind of stuff: authorizing a client request, send the query to elasticsearch/solr, and sending it back to the client (*with or without data processing on the way back*).    PHP is less suitable if you have many connections (something nodejs is great for).

---

See the second part of [this article](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2012/08/22/javascript-web-applications-and-elasticsearch.html) at elasticsearch's blog.  There's a nice illustration of a proxy, and a simple [Ruby code for the proxy](https://gist.github.com/3369662#file_proxy.rb).

Relevant quote from there:

> This all is possible by leveraging the fact that elasticsearch exposes an HTTP API. By putting a proxy in front of it, we can isolate the authentication and authorization routines into separate components, effectively de-composing the responsibilities in the stack and allowing for better testability of individual parts.

Comment: How could I overlook nodejs :)

Comment: Yes.  NodeJS is exactly for this kind of situations..   speed, concurrency, and simplicity.    You can also run it as a separate process, on a different cpu from your main site - which will give you a very lean and easy to maintain server.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a layer that act as a proxy but the best way to do it is to use the Replication (two or more instances - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication)

This way, you always have a valid, strong and usually private master index, on which you add, delete and do whatever you want, and a slave index which is only a copy of the master index and which does just provide the querying API.

Comment: Is it standard practice to have a master and slave for search?  I know with Solr that indexing a large amount of data can have massive performance issues, which my understanding is one of the strengths of ES.

Comment: I thought it was a standard, but maybe I'm wrong. I only worked with Solr and not more than 800k docs in it - I wanted to try ES but went to another Job before being able to. We always used a master-slave design, for security and easy to use. You can index and do whatever you want in the master, the slave is always available for the public. Then when master is good, slave replicate (really quickly). That design allow you to NEVER have your public index busy and not ready to be queried